# Synchronous transformation jobs using kettle

Tags: pentaho, etl, synchronous, kettle, spoon

Is there any way to run transformation jobs for synchronous calls ? The requirement is like for each API call I need to execute the ktr and return the response. Synchronous calls might happen , input file size can also change , can I handle this requirement using kettle transformation? Please help.

Comment: is not clear where kettle has to return the response and wich response.

Comment: Input:- xml string to ktr and output: - transformed xml generated as a result of executing ktr.(finale step of ktr is xml generation) ,that output i hv to return it as a webservice response.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the REST Client kettle step to communicate at the end of your transformation the data or any message to the api. I usually do.

Comment: Rest client will make another Web service call r8? Thats not my case,

Comment: 1. Exposed a webservice using spring 2.On a request , i will pass the input xml string to a ktr transformation job and the same execution thread will return the ktr output xml as a string and send the same as response of my webservice.My doubt is even if the same api is hitted by a million users how that synchronisation happen in kettle,or do we need to configure anything in the job to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with the EE server, you can expose transformations as webservices.

If you want to do it with CE then carte will help you. But it doesnt seem to support waiting for the job/trans to finish.

So if you want that option, then use CDA or SPARKL to expose your job or transformation as a webservice within the BA server and that will give you what you're looking for.